# Gunicorn working in Docker but not in AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, gunicorn

My flask app is structured as

```
webapp
  -- __init___.py    (app and server are initialized here)
  -- stuff.py
Dockerfile
entrypoint.sh
```

Dockerfile last line: `ENTRYPOINT ["sh","./entrypoint.sh"]`

Inside entrypoint.sh: `gunicorn -w 1 --timeout 1800 --bind :80 webapp:server`  Also tried `webapp.__init__:server`, `webapp:app.server`, `webapp:app`

This works on docker with the following result:

```
[INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:80 (9)
[INFO] Using worker: sync
[INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
```

but running on AWS beanstalk I get the follow:

```
[INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:80 (9)
[INFO] Using worker: sync
[INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
Failed to find attribute 'server' in 'webapp'.
[INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
[INFO] Shutting down: Master
[INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
```

server is inside webapp. Can gunicorn not handle `__init__.py`? But it works on local docker.